# Iphone Retina Display with Core Data user-generated images

Tags: iphone, core-data, image-scaling, retina-display

I have been looking at this forum on this topic for a while now and still don't have a clear picture of how to store images in Core Data successfully for Retina Display.

I understand that storing images through Core Data may not be the best for everyone, but in cases where it is being done for one reason or another, it is important to understand how these images are read and displayed.

Since the images don't have a file extension, the retina versions (if they exist) obviously cannot have a 2x extension.

So I am hoping someone can advise me as to how to what resolutions would be best to store bitmap images created through the app so that they have the best display in both retina and non-retina devices.

For example, if on my non-retina 3GS iPhone I have a UIImageView that displays a 55x60 image, I currently store an image "thumbnail" that is 55x60.

On the retina display, obviously I would like to have an image that is 110x120 to display.

But, since I can't create an image with an extension in core-data, how would I go about doing this?

If I decide just to create one image that will be used for both devices, do I just go with a 110x120 image? How does that work - will it use the full image for the retina display device and scale down the image for the non-retina device? Or (and I hope NOT) will it scale the image down for the non-retina device and scale it back up again for retina?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost: don't store images in Core Data.  It is just easier (and more performant!) to store an image on the filesystem (ie. documents directory) and use Core Data to store the *reference*.

That said, if you are insistent in using Core Data to store that data, you could store the Retina version and then detect when you are on a non-retina device and do an in-memory scale to the non-Retina version.

Comment: Thanks, I already store images in CoreData and I will try to change it in the future. (Side note - doesn't storing images in the filesystem make backup/restore and iCloud storage significantly more complicated?). In any case, for the time being, I want to find the best solution for storing images in Core Data. Are you saying that if I store the retina version (say 110x120 in my example) that it will automatically display that resolution in a retina device without me doing any work? Then, wouldn't it also automatically scale the image down for the non-retina device without me doing any work?

Comment: It will scale if your image view is setup to do so.

Comment: I don't think it's imageView specific - I guess what I meant to ask is: is there any 'automatic' scaling done on an image when it is a core data image (vs an image with an extension fetched via UIImage imagedNamed, etc). Images with extensions are automatically scaled up for retina display if a 2x version does not exist. If this is an image from core data, is there any automatic scaling based on device?

Comment: Sorry Wayne, re-reading your answer.. just to clarify - what is an in-memory scale?

Comment: Scale it using a graphics context: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/graphics/how-to-scale-an-image-using-an-objective-c-category.html

Answer (score 0):

Is part of the reason you want to store UIImages in CoreData so that your Images do not get "Cleaned" automatically by the OS?

If not, you should do as Wayne mentioned and just create references to a file path in the Documents directory.

If "cleaning" is the problem you are trying to avoid, then just store the UIImage's NSData as one of the NSManagedObject's properties, and then upon use scale it appropriately. Alternatively, you could always scale the images before putting them into CoreData.

Comment: I am using Core Data because I modeled my image storage after the Core Data Recipes sample app when I first started. Currently, lots of people are actively using the app, and I am not ready to change everything up just yet. If I were starting from scratch that would be a different answer... and when I say I store the image, I use the ImageToDataTransformer - is that the same thing as storing the image's NSData? I do scale the images before putting them into core data, but I am not sure how to best go about doing that for retina display to work properly.